# Comparing EPA emission limits between wood stoves and wood furnaces

Tags: heating-systems, combustion, wood

Emission limits set by the EPA were updated in 2020.

Currently, "Wood-burning stoves" are allowed 2.5 grams/hour of smoke emission [[1]](https://www.epa.gov/burnwise/choosing-right-wood-burning-stove). On the other hand, "Wood-burning forced-air furnaces" are limited to 0.15 pounds per million BTU heat output [[2]](https://www.epa.gov/residential-wood-heaters/fact-sheet-summary-requirements-wood-fired-forced-air-furnaces).

Comparing these two units would require knowing how much heat output (in BTU) a stove outputs per hour. This must vary quite a bit, simply by how much wood you happen to be burning.

Are there general statements that can be made regarding this comparison? I'd love to know, for example, if one is always better (i.e. less smoke output) than the other.

Or am I going to have to start digging into spec sheets and doing conversions?